# OnItemClickListener for RecyclerView in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am trying to open a url link when I click on a list item in a recyclerview but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. I am using a ViewPager, I don't know if this is the cause of the exception, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Please check out my code and logcat below.

This is my adapter:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsHolder> {

private ArrayList<News> mNews = new ArrayList<>();
private static ClickListener clickListener;

public NewsAdapter(ArrayList<News> news) {
    mNews = news;
}

private static String timeConverter(String inputTime) {
    long startTime = 0;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    simpleDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    try {
        Date date = simpleDate.parse(inputTime);
        startTime = date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long end = currentTime - startTime;

    long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(end);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(minutes);

    if (minutes > 59) {
        return hours + "h";
    }else if (seconds > 59) {
        return minutes + "m";
    }else {
        return seconds + "s";
    }
}

@Override
public NewsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_view, parent, false);
    return new NewsHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NewsHolder holder, int position) {
    String imagePath = mNews.get(position).getImageUrl();
    Picasso.with(holder.mImageView.getContext()).load(imagePath).into(holder.mImageView);

    holder.mNewsTextView.setText(mNews.get(position).getNews());
    holder.mTimeStampTextView.setText(timeConverter(mNews.get(position).getTime()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNews.size();
}

//    NewsHolder class that extends the ViewHolder
public static class NewsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mNewsTextView;
    private TextView mTimeStampTextView;

    //   Setting the views
    public NewsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simple_imageView);
        mNewsTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_tv);
        mTimeStampTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), view);
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener listener) {
    NewsAdapter.clickListener = listener;
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}

}
```

This is one of my ViewPager fragments:

```
public class TechFragment extends Fragment {
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private TextView mErrorMessage;
private NewsAdapter mNewsAdapter;
ArrayList<News> news;
NetworkInfo info;
//  The Loader takes in a bundle
Bundle sourceBundle = new Bundle();

private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String TECH_NEWS_QUERY_URL = "query";
private static final String TECH_NEWS_SOURCE = "techcrunch";
private static final String TECH_SOURCE_CATEGORY = "latest";
private static final int TECH_NEWS_LOADER = 22;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

public TechFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    mErrorMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_main);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(TECH_NEWS_LOADER, sourceBundle, new NewsDataLoader());

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Refreshing");
            restartLoader();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
                    R.color.colorPrimary,
                    R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

private int anyRandomInt(Random random) {
    return random.nextInt();
}

private void restartLoader() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL techNewsUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(TECH_NEWS_SOURCE, TECH_SOURCE_CATEGORY);
            sourceBundle.putString(TECH_NEWS_QUERY_URL, techNewsUrl.toString());

            Random random = new Random();
            int uniqueId = anyRandomInt(random); //Generates a new ID for each loader call;

            LoaderManager loaderManager = getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager();

            if (loaderManager.getLoader(TECH_NEWS_LOADER) == null) {
                loaderManager.initLoader(uniqueId, sourceBundle, new NewsDataLoader());
            } else {
                loaderManager.restartLoader(TECH_NEWS_LOADER, sourceBundle, new
                        NewsDataLoader());
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Finished refreshing");
}

private void showErrorScreen() {
    mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mErrorMessage.setText(getString(R.string.internet_error));
}

public class NewsDataLoader implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<News>> {
    @Override
    public Loader<ArrayList<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle args) {
        if (isConnected()) {
            mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return new AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<News>>(getActivity()) {
                ArrayList<News> mNewsData;

                @Override
                protected void onStartLoading() {
                    super.onStartLoading();
                    if (mNewsData != null) {
                        deliverResult(mNewsData);
                    } else {
                        forceLoad();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public ArrayList<News> loadInBackground() {
                    try {
                        ArrayList<News> news = NetworkUtils.parseJSON(TECH_NEWS_SOURCE, TECH_SOURCE_CATEGORY);
                        return news;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                public void deliverResult(ArrayList<News> data) {
                    mNewsData = data;
                    super.deliverResult(data);
                }
            };
        } else {
            showErrorScreen();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<News>> loader, final ArrayList<News> data) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        if (null == data) {
            showErrorScreen();
        } else {
            mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (news != null) {
                news.clear();
                news.addAll(data);
                mNewsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(news);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNewsAdapter);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                mNewsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                news = data;
            }
        }
        mNewsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NewsAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                News currentNews = news.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentNews.getUrl()));
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null){
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<News>> loader) {
    }

}

}
```

And this is my error:

```
06-13 12:11:38.667 3890-3890/com.ire.blogbot E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.ire.blogbot, PID: 3890
                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ire.blogbot.adapter.NewsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(com.ire.blogbot.adapter.NewsAdapter$ClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                               at com.ire.blogbot.fragments.TechFragment$NewsDataLoader.onLoadFinished(TechFragment.java:192)
                                                               at com.ire.blogbot.fragments.TechFragment$NewsDataLoader.onLoadFinished(TechFragment.java:131)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:476)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:444)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:126)
                                                               at com.ire.blogbot.fragments.TechFragment$NewsDataLoader$1.deliverResult(TechFragment.java:164)
                                                               at com.ire.blogbot.fragments.TechFragment$NewsDataLoader$1.deliverResult(TechFragment.java:137)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:252)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:80)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.finish(ModernAsyncTask.java:485)
                                                               at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(ModernAsyncTask.java:502)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: news object probably is null, and  mNewsAdapter not initialized so you can't call setOnItemClickListener on null object.

Comment: You are initializing the mNewsAdapter when news object is not null, then why don't you move setOnItemClickListener part inside that same if condition where you perform null check on news object.

Comment: Thank you. That stopped the crash. But I have noticed the click action is not working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
mNewsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NewsAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
                News currentNews = news.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentNews.getUrl()));
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null){
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

after

```
mNewsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(news);
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked but the click action is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it is working

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                   // on click 
                }
            })
    );
```

RecyclerItemClickListener Class

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working for me!